# Error 1093: Query has same value of where in UPDATE and SET

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to update my table using the following

```
UPDATE timeline SET c_flag=(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2014-09-29 7:00:00',(SELECT reference_log FROM timeline WHERE venture_id=33))) >= 48) WHERE venture_id=33;
```

But I consequently get

```
ERROR 1093 : You can't specify target table 'timeline' for update in FROM clause
```

What is the appropriate query for this?

Comment: Do you really need a sub query ?

Comment: Yes, I think so, because I'm dealing with values on the same row and on the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subquery not required here, just try this:

```
UPDATE timeline
 SET c_flag = (HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2014-09-29 7:00:00', reference_log)) >= 48)
 WHERE venture_id=33;
```